# PHP - Create and download ZipArchive returns CPGZ when opening

Tags: php, zip

The function does not seem to be creating the ZIP file properly. The file prompt to downloads works fine. However when opening it, it just creates copy with `.cpgz` format.

For reference:
`foreach ($attachments as $file)` outputs as `"/upload/image.jpg"`

```
function downloadAttachment() {
    $zipname = 'attachments.zip';
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
    foreach ($attachments as $file) {
      $fileSrc = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . $file["file_attachment"];
      $zip->addFile($fileSrc);
    }
    $zip->close();

    header('Content-Type: application/zip');
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename='.$zipname);
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($zipname);
}
```

Comment: do you have permission to create `./attachments.zip` in your php directory ? so i mean before  `readfile($zipname);` what gives you  `var_dump( file_exists($zipname) )` ?

Comment: `file_exists($zipname)` = `false`. I am a dork. How would I set the path so I create `attachement.zip` at `/uploads/all_attachements/attachments.zip`?

Comment: check detailed answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `dirname(__FILE__)` - it return you absolute path to your current php script, make `var_dump( dirname(__FILE__) )` to see what it gives you and then relocate with `../` or `/folders/..` to your attachments directory

so your `$zipname` will be something like `$zipname = dirname(__FILE__) .'/../some_folders/attachements/attachments.zip'`;

and make sure that directory is writable by `www-data` user or just `chmod` it `0777` in any case

`__FILE__` is one of PHP's magic constants you can check more here - http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

one more good practice is to define somewhere in `configs.php` which is included on every php `define('ROOT_DIR', "absolute root path of your project");` then use `ROOT_DIR` variable everywhere in your project as prefix for all folders `ROOT_DIR."/folder/file ..."`